# Get text without hyphen - Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a table row element

```
<th scope="row" class="u-printHyphensManual row">
            Advan­&shy;taged
</th>
```

How to I get text without the hyphen? i.e `elem.text` returns `"Advantaged"` and NOT `"Advan-taged"`.

I am using capybara.

Comment: This is unclear. Are you looking to strip all HTML entities?

Comment: No. I am just looking to get the node text in Capybara. That is find('th').text, this however returns text with a hyphen and I want without hyphen. Looking for a way to normalize text at the time of finding

Comment: Please describe the 'normalization' you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a Unicode character into a string by putting in the code and using string.encode, or you can put the code directly in a regex. The Unicode for a soft hyphen is \u00AD

`text.gsub('\u00AD'.encode('utf-8'), '')`

or

`text.gsub(/\u00AD/, '')`

If that doesn't work try replacing literal `&shy;`

`text.gsub('&shy;', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Change `find('th').text` to `find('th').text.gsub(/[^A-za-z]/,'')`.

This works for this case, but depending on what general problem you're really trying to solve, this may have unintended consequences.

Comment: It doesn't work as it's not a string character. I have tried gsub also

Comment: Then you specify the text you want to keep. Does Capybara resolve the entity or do you get literal '&', 's', 'h', 'y', ';' ?